# How to select record of a list using Reflection

Tags: c#, list, reflection

```
 string className = "CustomerEntities[2]"
 PropertyInfo propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty(className);
```

propertyInfo is always null, how do I select class at an certain index of a list i.e. 2. However if I change the class name to "CustomerEntities", It selects an entire list.

Comment: That's right. The property name is `CustomerEntities` and it _is_ a list. So get that list with `list = propertyInfo.GetValue(model)` and get your desired result via `list[2]`.

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes but is there any short way to directly select the property? using `className = "CustomerEntities[2]"`

Comment: No. `CustomerEntities[2]` _is no property of model_! The property is `CustomerEntities` and the `[ ]` is an indexer property of _the type of that list_. There is no short way.

Comment: can you post the class that `model` variable,

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the value of the whole list and then select the record which you want from that list, here is the example supposing you the "CustomerEntities" is of type List

```
string className = "CustomerEntities";
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty(className);
List<string> result = (List<string>) propertyInfo.GetValue(model);
string record = result[2];
```